# How to capture every match in a global regex substitution?

Tags: regex, perl, substitution

I realize it is possible to achieve this with a slight workaround, but I am hoping there is a simpler way (since I often make use of this type of expression).

Given the example string:

```
my $str = "An example: sentence!*"
```

A regex can be used to match each punctuation mark and capture them in an array.
Thereafter, I can simply repeat the regex and replace the matches as in the following code:

```
push (@matches, $1), while ($str =~ /([\*\!:;])/);
$str =~ s/([\*\!:;])//g;
```

Would it be possible to combine this into a single step in Perl where substitution occurs globally while also keeping tabs on the replaced matches?

Comment: What do you need to "keep tabs"? What's the other part of the task where that's necessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can embed code to run in your regular expression:

```
my @matches;
my $str = 'An example: sentence!*';
$str =~ s/([\*\!:;])(?{push @matches, $1})//g;
```

But with a match this simple, I'd just do the captures and substitution separately.

Comment: I was gonna say this doesn't work in subs, but it looks like someone (you?) [fixed it in 5.18](https://pastebin.com/nHwivbbP).

Comment: wasn't me :)  I remembered there being a problem, but tried it on the versions I had easily available and didn't see it.  in any case, pre-5.18, use `local our @matches;` instead of my.  thanks for tracking down the version it was fixed in.  (on some much earlier versions, I think you didn't get the variable will not stay shared but might get crashes)

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
my $str = "An example: sentence!*";
my @matches = $str =~  /([\*\!:;])/g;
say Dumper \@matches;
$str =~ tr/*!:;//d;
```

**Output:**

```
$VAR1 = [
          ':',
          '!',
          '*'
        ];
```

Comment: @ikegami: You're right, I just forgot the remove part. Fixed.

Comment: ok, but the OP was asking how to avoid the pattern repetition. Maybe add a line explaining why you think that's not necessary?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible.

```
my @matches;
$str =~ s/[*!:;]/ push @matches, $&; "" /eg;
```

However, I'm not convinced that the above is faster or clearer than the following:

```
my @matches = $str =~ /[*!:;]/g;
$str =~ tr/*!:;//d;
```

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you're looking for ?

```
my ($str, @matches) = ("An example: sentence!*");

#first method : 
($str =~ s/([\*\!:;])//g) && push(@matches, $1);

#second method : 
push(@matches, $1) while ($str =~ s/([\*\!:;])//g);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
my $str = "An example: sentence!*";

push(@mys, ($str=~m/([^\w\s])/g));

print join "\n", @mys;
```

Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't remove the marks from the value of `$str`.

Comment: The punctuation marks `*`, `!`, `:` and  `;` are supposed to be removed from `$str`, but they aren't.